# How can I get the size of WAL per hour?

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

I want to get statistics wal. We need to stop replication for a while so l want to know query for getting how much size of WAL produce per hour.
In Oracle it just get redo log switch count from statistics table. Is there something like this in PostgreSQL?

Thanks.

Comment: [pg_stat_archiver](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ARCHIVER-VIEW) and [pg_stat_bgwriter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-BGWRITER-VIEW) might be what you are looking for

Comment: thanks. Actually, I used RDS and found the exact metrics from CloudWatch.